# Overwriting moment.now() in a typescript application

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a task to synchronize MomentJS with server time in an Angular2 application.

MomentJS has a feature to change time source as it stated [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/)

But typescript compiler doesn't allow me to overwrite the moment#now() function, as it exported as a function from a namespace in moment.d.ts, so I get the error.

> Can't assign to 'now' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

Meanwhile moment.d.ts has a comment for the moment#now:

> //... Overwrite for profit

So I assume I do something wrong.

I use angular-cli rc4, MomentJS 2.18.1 and import it as

> import * as moment from "moment";

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can always bypass the type checking by casting it to `any` if nothing else works out: `(moment as any).now = () => { return 1; }`

Comment: How are you trying to invoque the function, in a variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "typescript compiler doesn't allow me to overwrite the `moment#now()` function, as it exported as a function from a namespace in `moment.d.ts`, so I get the error."

These sorts of constraints are pre-compile only which means that you can tell typescript to essentially ignore and let you override by casting it to an `any`.

```
import * as moment from "moment";

// temporary cast as any to override.
(moment as any).now = () => serverDateTime

// continue with moment intellisense
```